# check if current page url contains certain words

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a way to make it so that you can check if your current page url contains things like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15` the problem is this format could literally go on forever and at any random time I would need to make it so that one of the numbers doesn't display.

Currently I'm using a system like this to gather the current page URL.

```
$d = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $d[0];
```

However I'm unfamiliar how we could simply check the URL for certain parts and then redirect it back to the index page.

**EDIT:** This is my current code (Note I'm using *laravel*).

```
if (strpos($d, '19') !== false) {       
    header( 'Location: http://example.com' ) ;
} else { ?>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @if( strlen( $link->password ) )
        <p class="bg-warning" style="padding: 8px;">Enter password to continue</p>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:1.5rem;">
                    @endif
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ $link->text }}</button>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Sorry for the messy code, Just trying to figure out how I can achieve this without having numerous `strpos` and actually have it echo out the form as right now it does not.

Comment: Do you mean:  example.com/index.php?something=1,2,3,4,5... **or** example.com/index.php?1,2,3,4,5... **or** example.com/index.php?something=1&something2=2&something3=3&something2=4&something5=5...

Comment: It would be something like this -> xample.com/index.php?id=1 then another url would be xample.com/index.php?id=2

Answer (score 0):

if you get data from url and page is like this test.php?id=1 you directly access the data using $_GET method and process them. In my case i access the dirctly $_GET["id"], its return value 1. so you directly compare value.

Thanks.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, updated my question please view

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck, that feature is literally **built-in** to php!

```
<?php

echo $_GET['id']; //fetches whatever is after the id= (and before the next '&') example.com?id=WhateverComesHere

?>
```

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, updated my question please view